# Change inner text and class when submitting in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to change the inner text of  tag when the form is subbmitting?

For example, I have this HTML code:

```
<form>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click to the button or press Enter key, the submit text will change to processing or something like that. A class will be added to the button element..etc.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried?

Comment: Try to use `$('form').submit(function(){$('button').text('something');});`

Answer (score 2):

What element do you want to change? You can identify it a number of ways. The most common ways are by ID or class

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $('#element_id').text('what_you_want_to_write');
   $('#element_id').attr('class', 'new_class_name');
   return false;
});
```

Or, you can change the class name by doing

```
$('#element_id').addClass('new_class_name');
```

Comment: Yeah, you can use that too

Answer (score 1):

you can add a handler to the submit event of the form like

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button').text('Processing');
    //form submission logic goes here if any
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change html:

```
<form>
<button id="submitButton" onclick="changeText()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function changeText()
{
    document.getElementById("submitButton").innerHTML="Processing...";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're doing a lot of unnecessary work here check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xRFfy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

### code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        $(this).val("Processing....");
        $(this).addClass('processing');
         $('#frm1').submit();
      });
});
```

### html

```
<form id="frm1">
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

### css

```
.processing
{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
```